# custom delegate is not getting called in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi all I am using Xcode 8 and I am trying to use delegate to pass object between two view controller but somehow delegate method is not getting called.I tried to rectify but I am unable to do it.can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here.Thank you.Here is my code

**VideoViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "VideoCollection.h"



//delegate methods
@class VideoViewController;
@protocol AddVideoDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)addVideoToCollectionView:(VideoViewController*)viewController didAddVideo:(VideoCollection*)object;

@end

@interface VideoViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>
- (instancetype)initWithVideoUrl:(NSURL *)url;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *videoUrl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayer *avPlayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerLayer *avPlayerLayer;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *cancelButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *captionField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dataArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *pickerView;

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<AddVideoDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

**VideoViewController.m**

```
-(void)addButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button{
    //
    id<AddVideoDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;
    if ([strongDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addVideoToCollectionView:didAddVideo:)]) {
        VideoCollection* videoCollection=[[VideoCollection alloc] init];
        videoCollection.videoCaption=self.captionField.text;
        videoCollection.videoURL=_videoUrl;
        videoCollection.videoType=self.videoTypeLabel.text;
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        videoCollection.captionHeightPercentage=(self.captionField.frame.origin.y*100)/screenRect.size.height;

        [strongDelegate addVideoToCollectionView:self didAddVideo:(VideoCollection *)videoCollection];

    }
 NSLog(@"added");
}
```

**videoCollectionViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "VideoViewController.h"

@interface videoCollectionViewController : UIViewController<AddVideoDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (strong, nonatomic) VideoViewController* _vc;
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)sfds:(id)sender;

@end
```

**videoCollectionViewController.m**

```
#import "videoCollectionViewController.h"
#import "WebSerivceInterface.h"
#import "VideoViewController.h"

@interface videoCollectionViewController ()

@end

@implementation videoCollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    __vc=[[VideoViewController alloc] init];
    __vc.delegate=self;





}
-(void)addVideoToCollectionView:(VideoViewController *)viewController didAddVideo:(VideoCollection *)object{
    NSLog(@"delegate called");
    self.label.text=object.videoCaption;
}
@end
```

Comment: Hi Riya, can you make the property of your delegate in VideoViewController.h class and then try to pass the data between two controllers. make sure your delegate property must be weak.

Comment: @MandeepSingh I partially added videoViewController.h in question but its there in a file

Comment: what is your VideoViewController, is it subclass of uiview?

Comment: @MandeepSingh I have edited the question

Comment: This is not the way to call the delegate in your videoCollectionViewController Class.

Comment: @MandeepSingh Even I tried without   __vc=[[VideoViewController alloc] init];
    __vc.delegate=self; still it won't work

Comment: `__vc=[[VideoViewController alloc] init];` That's a the creation of anew object. Do you present it? Check the address of `__vc` `videoCollectionViewController` in and `self` in `addButtonPressed:`.

Comment: Where are you telling the videoViewController that the videoCollectionViewController is the delegate? I can't find it in your code. You tell the videoViewController that the strongDelegate is the delegate, but I don't see what value the delegate has.

Comment: @Larme yes I presenting it

Comment: please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748950/ios-pass-data-back-from-viewcontroller2-to-viewcontroller-1-with-presentmodalseg/33751609#33751609

Comment: @riyaahuja did your delegate works?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suppose you create your own custom delegate method in Class A and You need to access that method in Class B. So When you are pushing or presenting from Class B To Class A Like this:-

```
ViewController *objView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
objView.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objView animated:true];
```

ViewController is your Class A in which you have created your delegate, then you can be able to access your delegate Method in Class B.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here :

```
   (void)addButtonPressed:(UIButton *)button{
   //
   id<AddVideoDelegate> strongDelegate = self.delegate;
   if ([strongDelegate 
respondsToSelector:@selector(addVideoToCollectionView:didAddVideo:)]) {
       VideoCollection* videoCollection=[[VideoCollection alloc] init];
        videoCollection.videoCaption=self.captionField.text;
       videoCollection.videoURL=_videoUrl;
        videoCollection.videoType=self.videoTypeLabel.text;
     CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
                 videoCollection.captionHeightPercentage= 
  (self.captionField.frame.origin.y*100)/screenRect.size.height;         
 [strongDelegate addVideoToCollectionView:self didAddVideo
      (VideoCollection *)videoCollection];
}
NSLog(@"added");
}
```

You are trying set delegate self here that means it will back to this class. But the delegate also set from caller class. Delegate always should set from that class where the method is implemented. Simply remove the line

id strongDelegate = self.delegate;
  and set the delegate before push/present the vc.
Sorry for bad language